# Define start order of independent sbt tasks

Tags: scala, sbt

I have 4 independent sbt tasks that I'd like to have run in parallel under one overall task. However, one task takes significantly longer than the others. I'd like to start that task first and and then the others so that the overall task finishes as fast as possible. I've defined my overall task as follows:

```
overallTask := {
  task1.value
  task2.value
  task3.value
  task4.value
}
```

This has the desired effect of the tasks running in parallel but I've noticed that `task1` does not always start first. I don't want to have the other tasks depend on the output of `task1` as then it must wait for it to complete. How can I force `task1` to start before the others without waiting for its output?

Comment: You can run them in a sequence: https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto-Sequential-Task.html

Comment: @laughedelic if I use sequential, then wouldn't task2 not start until task1 is complete? Wouldn't this mean I'd lose the parallelization of those tasks?

Comment: Correct. But I think this is your best bet to control the order. You can also do it through dependencies as you mention, but sbt calculates dependencies between tasks and evaluates the dependencies first. You can validate when the tasks start by adding some printlns.

Comment: Here's relevant documentation: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Custom-Settings.html#Execution+semantics+of+tasks